# An inequality involving 2 variables

Tags: inequalities

How to prove that the following expression is positive for $u\ge 0$ and $q\in(0,\pi/3)$. $$\frac{2 \sqrt{2} ((2+u) (1+\cos(q)))^{3/4}}{3^{3/4}}-\frac{2^{3/4} (1+\sec(q))}{\sqrt{3} \sec(q)^{3/4}}-\left(1+u+\sqrt{-1+(1+u)^2} \sqrt{1-\frac{4 \sin(q)^2}{3}}\right)^{3/4}$$

Comment: can you give some motivation for this and similar questions <https://mathoverflow.net/q/450544/11260> ? they seem so arbitrary...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting $c:=\cos q$, we have $c\in[1/2,1]$. Writing $\sec q=1/c$ and $\sin^2q=1-c^2$, and multiplying the big expression by $3^{3/4}c^{1/4}$, we see that the inequality in question can be rewritten as
\begin{equation*}
    f(c,u)\overset{\text{(?)}}>0, \tag{10}\label{10}
\end{equation*}
where $(c,u)\in[1/2,1]\times[0,\infty)$,
\begin{equation*}
    f(c,u):=\big(1-(r_1(c,u)+r_2(c,u))\big)\,2\sqrt2\, (c (1 + c)^3 (2 + u)^3)^{1/4}, 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
    r_1(c,u):=\frac{\sqrt[4]{3}}{2^{3/4}}\, \sqrt[4]{\frac{c+1}{c (u+2)^3}},\quad 
    r_2(c,u):=\frac1{2 \sqrt{2}}\,
    \left(\frac{\sqrt{3} \sqrt{\left(4 c^2-1\right) u (u+2)}+3 u+3}{c u+2
   c+u+2}\right)^{3/4}. 
\end{equation*}

So, it is enough to show that
\begin{equation*}
    r_1(c,u)+r_2(c,u)\overset{\text{(?)}}<1. \tag{20}\label{20}
\end{equation*}

Note that $r_1(c,u)$ is decreasing in $c\in[1/2,1]$ and in $[0,\infty)$. So,
\begin{equation*}
    r_1(c,u)\le r_1(1/2,73/10)<1-\frac{3^{3/4}}{2 \sqrt{2}}\quad
    \text{for }(c,u)\in[1/2,1]\times[73/10,\infty). 
\end{equation*}
Next, for all $(c,u)\in[1/2,1]\times[0,\infty)$
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
    &\big((2\sqrt2\,r_2(c,u))^{4/3}-3\big) \\ 
    &\times (c+1) (u+2) \left(\sqrt{3} \sqrt{\left(4 c^2-1\right) u (u+2)}+3 c u+6 c+3\right) \\ 
    &=\left(3-3 c^2\right) u^2+6 \left(2 c^2+3 c+1\right) u+9 (2 c+1)^2,
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
which is manifestly $>0$, whence $r_2(c,u)<\dfrac{3^{3/4}}{2 \sqrt{2}}$.
So, we have \eqref{20} and hence \eqref{10} for $(c,u)\in[1/2,1]\times[73/10,\infty)$.

It remains to prove \eqref{10} for $(c,u)\in[1/2,1]\times[0,73/10]$.

To do this, note that
\begin{equation}
    f(c,u)=f_1(c,u)-f_2(c,u), 
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}
    f_1(c,u):=2 \sqrt{2} \sqrt[4]{c (c+1)^3 (u+2)^3}-2^{3/4} \sqrt[4]{3} (c+1), 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    f_2(c,u):=\sqrt[4]{c \left(\sqrt{3} \sqrt{\left(4 c^2-1\right) u (u+2)}+3 u+3\right)^3}. 
\end{equation}
Clearly, $f_2(c,u)$ is increasing in $c\in[1/2,1]$ and in $[0,\infty)$.

Also clearly, $f_1(c,u)$ is increasing in $u\in[0,\infty)$.
Also,
\begin{equation}
    g_1(c,u):=\partial_c f_1(c,u)=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}
    \Big(\frac{(4 c+1) (u+2)^{3/4}}{\sqrt[4]{c^3 (c+1)}}-2 \sqrt[4]{6}\Big)
    \ge g_1(c,0)
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
    \partial_c g_1(c,0)=-\frac{3}{2\ 2^{3/4} c^{7/4} (c+1)^{5/4}}<0. 
\end{equation}
So, $g_1(c,u)\ge g_1(c,0)\ge g_1(1,0)=2.78\ldots>0$. So, $f_1(c,u)$ is increasing in $c\in[1/2,1]$.
So, $f_1(c,u)$ is increasing in $c\in[1/2,1]$ and in $[0,\infty)$.

So, "partitioning" the rectangle $[0,73/10]$ into $20\times200=4000$ congruent rectangles, with vertices $(c_i,u_j):=(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{i}{20},\frac{73}{10}\frac{j}{200})$,
for all $(c,u)\in[1/2,1]\times[0,73/10]$ we get
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
f(c,u) 
\ge\min\big\{f_1 & \big(c_{i-1},u_{j-1}\big)
    -f_2\big(c_i,u_j\big) \colon  \\ 
    &i=1,\dots,20,\,j=1,\dots,200\big\}=0.0247\ldots>0. 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
This completes the proof of \eqref{10}. $\quad\Box$

Answer (score 1):

First let's multiply the given expression by $\left(\frac92\sec(q)\right)^{3/4}$ and simplify it into
$$\left(6(2+u) (\sec(q)+1)\right)^{3/4}-3 (1+\sec(q))-\left(\frac92(1+u)\sec(q)+\frac92\sqrt{-1+(1+u)^2} \sqrt{\frac{4-\sec(q)^2}{3}}\right)^{3/4}$$
Let $v:=\sec(q)$ and thus $v\in[1,2]$. Then, let $p:=(6(2+u) (v+1))^{1/4}$ and $r:=\left(\frac92(1+u)v+\frac92\sqrt{u^2+2u} \sqrt{\frac{4-v^2}{3}}\right)^{1/4}$. Correspondingly, the original question is equivalent to showing that the following system of polynomial equations and inequalities is insoluble:
$$\begin{cases}
p^4 - 6(2+u) (v+1) = 0, \\
(2r^4 - 9(1+u)v)^2 - 27(u^2+2u)(4-v^2) = 0,\\
p\geq0, \\
r\geq0, \\
u\geq 0, \\
1 \leq v \leq 2, \\
p^3 - 3(1+v) - r^3 \leq 0.
\end{cases}$$
This formulation makes the problem amenable to existing software. A few examples and links can be seen in the answers to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/435267).

Answer (score 0):

*Remarks*: Here is a human verifiable proof. The same strategy as [my answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450544/an-inequality-for-a-real-function/451223#451223) for another question of the same author is used.
The proof of (1), (2) and (3) is not difficult by using Bernoulli inequality and letting $x = \cos q \in [1/2, 1]$, and thus omitted here.

For convenience, let
$$a := \frac{2 \sqrt{2} (1+\cos q)^{3/4}}{3^{3/4}}, \quad
b := \frac{2^{3/4} (1+\sec q)}{\sqrt{3}\, 
    (\sec q)^{3/4}}, 
\quad c := \sqrt{1-\frac{4 \sin^2 q}{3}}.$$

We need to prove that, for all $u \ge 0$ and $q \in [0, \pi/3]$,
$$a(2 + u)^{3/4} - b + \left(1 + u + c\sqrt{-1 + (1 + u)^2}\right)^{3/4} \ge 0.$$

We split into three cases.

**Case 1**: $u > 10/9$

Using $\sqrt{-1 + (1 + u)^2} < 1 + u$, it suffices to prove that
$$g(u) := a(2 + u)^{3/4} - b - (1 + c)^{3/4}(1 + u)^{3/4} \ge 0.$$

We have
\begin{align*}
    g'(u) &= \frac{3a}{4(2 + u)^{1/4}} - \frac{3(1 + c)^{3/4}}{4(1 + u)^{1/4}}\\[6pt]
    &= \frac{3(1 + c)^{3/4}}{4(2 + u)^{1/4}}
    \left(\frac{a}{(1 + c)^{3/4}} - \left(1 + \frac{1}{1 + u}\right)^{1/4}\right)\\[6pt]
    &\ge \frac{3(1 + c)^{3/4}}{4(2 + u)^{1/4}}
    \left(\frac{a}{(1 + c)^{3/4}} - \left(1 + \frac{1}{1 + 10/9}\right)^{1/4}\right)\\[6pt]
    &> 0
\end{align*}
where we use the fact that, for all $q \in [0, \pi/3]$,
$$\left(\frac{a}{(1 + c)^{3/4}}\right)^{4/3} - \left(1 + \frac{1}{1 + 10/9}\right)^{1/3}
= \frac{4(1 + \cos q)}{3\left(1 + \sqrt{1-\frac{4 - 4 \cos^2 q}{3}}\right)} - \sqrt[3]{\frac{28}{19}} > 0.$$
(*Note*: Simply let $x = \cos q \in [1/2, 1]$. The rest is easy.)

Also, we have
$$g(10/9) = a(2 + 10/9)^{3/4} - b - (1 + c)^{3/4}(1 + 10/9)^{3/4} > 0. \tag{1}$$

Thus, we have $g(u) > 0$ for all $u > 10/9$.

$\phantom{2}$

**Case 2**: $1/5 < u \le 10/9$

We have
$\sqrt{-1 + (1 + u)^2} = 1 + u - \frac{1}{1 + u + \sqrt{-1 + (1 + u)^2}}
\le 1 + u - \frac14$.

It suffices to prove that
$$h(u) := a(2 + u)^{3/4} - b + \left(1 + u + c(u + 3/4)\right)^{3/4} \ge 0.$$

Letting $d := \frac{1 + 3c/4}{1 + c}$, we have
\begin{align*}
    h'(u) &= \frac{3a}{4(2+u)^{1/4}} - \frac{3(1 + c)^{3/4}}{4(u + d)^{1/4}}\\[6pt]
    &= \frac{3(1 + c)^{3/4}}{4(2 + u)^{1/4}}\left(\frac{a}{(1 + c)^{3/4}} - \left(1 + \frac{2 - d}{u + d}\right)^{1/4}\right)\\[6pt]
    &\ge \frac{3(1 + c)^{3/4}}{4(2 + u)^{1/4}}\left(\frac{a}{(1 + c)^{3/4}} - \left(16/7\right)^{1/4}\right)\\[6pt]
    & > 0
\end{align*}
where we use $1 + \frac{2-d}{u + d}
\le 1 + \frac{2-d}{d} = \frac{8 + 8c}{4 + 3c} \le 16/7$ (using $c\le 1$), and the fact that, for all $q \in [0, \pi/3]$,
$$\left(\frac{a}{(1 + c)^{3/4}}\right)^{4/3} - \left(16/7\right)^{1/3} = \frac{4(1 + \cos q)}{3\left(1 + \sqrt{1-\frac{4 - 4 \cos^2 q}{3}}\right)} - (16/7)^{1/3} > 0.$$
(*Note*: Simply let $x = \cos q \in [1/2, 1]$. The rest is easy.)

Also, we have
$$h(1/5) = a(2 + 1/5)^{3/4} - b + \left(1 + 1/5 + c(1/5 + 3/4)\right)^{3/4} > 0. \tag{2}$$

Thus, we have $h(u) > 0$ for all $1/5 < u \le 10/9$.

$\phantom{2}$

**Case 3**: $0\le u \le 1/5$

By Bernoulli inequality $(1 + z)^r \le 1 + zr$ for all $0 < r < 1$ and $z > -1$, we have
$$(2 + u)^{3/4} = \frac{2 + u}{2^{1/4} (1 + \frac{u}{2})^{1/4}}
\ge \frac{2 + u}{2^{1/4}(1 + \frac{u}{2}\cdot \frac14)}
\ge 2^{3/4}(1 + u/3)$$
where we use $2 + u \ge 2(1 + u/3)(1 + u/8)$.

Also, we have $\sqrt{-1 + (1 + u)^2} \le \sqrt{-1 + (1 + 1/5)^2}
< 2/3$.

It suffices to prove that
$$F(u) := a\cdot 2^{3/4}(1 + u/3) - b + \left(1 + u + 2c/3\right)^{3/4} \ge 0.$$

We have
\begin{align*}
    F'(u) &= \frac{2^{3/4}}{3}a - \frac{3}{4(1 + u + 2c/3)^{1/4}} \\[6pt]
    &\ge \frac{2^{3/4}}{3}\cdot \frac{2 \sqrt{2} (1+1/2)^{3/4}}{3^{3/4}} - \frac{3}{4}\\
    &> 0
\end{align*}
where we use
$a \ge \frac{2 \sqrt{2} (1+1/2)^{3/4}}{3^{3/4}}$.

Also, we have
$$F(0) = a\cdot 2^{3/4} - b + \left(1 + 2c/3\right)^{3/4} > 0. \tag{3}$$

Thus, we have $F(u) > 0$ for all $u \in [0, 1/5]$.

We are done.